# Passing 0 as an enum option into Objective C functions in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

There are Objective-C libraries with functions that take integer enum options as a parameter, but they expect you to pass 0 in if you want default options, as is typical. But in Swift, that is not allowed because the library specifies an enum type. Is there any way around this short of adding a 0 enum option to the libraries then making bridging code to make its ObjC enums work in Swift?

Here's an example with `SDWebImageManager` in an iPhone app:

```
SDWebImageManager.sharedManager().downloadWithURL(url, options: 0, progress: nil) { (image:UIImage!, error:NSError!, cacheType:SDImageCacheType, finished:Bool) -> Void in
            // block code here
        }
```

Xcode will point out an error where it says `options: 0` because `'Int' is not convertible to SDWebImageOptions`. I've tried something like the following, but I get the same error:

```
let emptyOptions:SDWebImageOptions = 0
```

Answer (score 5):

As of Swift 2, the syntax for option sets was changed to use array literals. So if you want to pass no options, you pass an empty list:

```
SDWebImageManager.sharedManager().downloadWithURL(url, options: [], progress: nil) { (image:UIImage!, error:NSError!, cacheType:SDImageCacheType, finished:Bool) -> Void in
    // code here
}
```

Comment: I get the error `SDWebImageOptions does not conform to protocol NilLiteralConvertible` when I try that. Sounds like Swift wants the `downloadWithURL`  function to accept an optional parameter for `options` if I do that, but of course ObjC doesn't support optional types.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of Xcode. This code should work. Enums declared in Objective-C with [`NS_OPTIONS`](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/#ns_options) become Structs which implement [`RawOptionSetType`](http://swiftdoc.org/protocol/RawOptionSetType/) in Swift. `RawOptionSetType` inherits to `NilLiteralConvertible`. As an alternative, you can use `SDWebImageOptions.allZeros` or `SDWebImageOptions(0)`.

Comment: How about `SDWebImageOptions(rawValue:0)`?